# Manipulate JSON String

Tags: javascript, json

Bit of a challenge I need to write some javascript which will do the following:

Search through a JSON string for something that looks like this

```
{"code_coverage_temp":["jacoco","pmd"]}
```

and then replace it with this

```
{"jacoco":true,"pmd":true}
```

It must be dynamic enough to deal with the values in array changing in size

I'm currently trying to find solution myself but any help would be appreciated

```
{ 
   "server":{ 
      "ip":"111.111.111.111",
      "credentials":{ 
         "username":"fwesf",
         "password":"fewfew"
      }
   },
   "pipeline":{ 
      "job":{ 
         "name":"gfhd"
      },
      "repository":{ 
         "name":"github",
         "location":"fwqfw",
         "credentials":{ 
            "username":"fsfs",
            "password":"fdsfdsf"
         }
      },
      "build":{ 
         "language":"java",
         "build_tool":"maven"
      },
      "test":{ 
         "bool":true,
         "test_type":"unit",
         "testing_framework":"junit5"
      },
      "static_code_analysis":{ 
         "bool":true,
         "code_coverage_temp":[ 
            "pmd",
            "jacoco"
         ]
      },
      "security_tools":{ 
         "bool":true,
         "security_tools_temp":[ 
            "zap"
         ]
      },
      "sonarcube":{ 
         "bool":true
      }
   }
}
```

added entire json im working with

Comment: Do you want to change it to:
{"code_coverage_temp":{"jacoco":true,"pmd":true}}
or
{"jacoco":true,"pmd":true}

Comment: **Don't** do it at the string level. Parse it, update the result, then stringify the updated version.

Comment: You're looking for the *key* `code_coverage_temp` and want to turn all its *values* into `...: true`…?

Comment: Hi guys, so firstly the value of array could change but will always have _temp at the end. To answer @Konowy it needs to change to {"jacoco":true,"pmd":true} yes @deceze exactly because everything selected is already true see entire part ```"static_code_analysis":{"bool":true,"code_coverage_temp":["jacoco","pmd"]}``` ...this is all inside one large json object

Comment: It must work this way to interact with another component which im not building

Comment: You don't need to operate changes in the JSON. [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to restore the data structure, operate on it then use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to create a new JSON out of it. In fact, your question is not about JSON at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` method of the `String`.

Since number of values in the array can change, you need to parse the matched string so that you can iterate over the array and put all the strings in the array in an object. Finally you need to `stringify` the object because replace method returns a string. You can parse returned string again to get the object if you need to.

## Edit

Since you posted your original json, following code will replace `"static_code_analysis":{"bool":true,"code_coverage_temp":["pmd","jacoco"]}` with `"static_code_analysis":{"bool":true,"cobertura":true,"jacoco":false,"pmd":true }`

```js
const jsonStr = '{"server":{"ip":"111.111.111.111","credentials":{"username":"fwesf","password":"fewfew"}},"pipeline":{"job":{"name":"gfhd"},"repository":{"name":"github","location":"fwqfw","credentials":{"username":"fsfs","password":"fdsfdsf"}},"build":{"language":"java","build_tool":"maven"},"test":{"bool":true,"test_type":"unit","testing_framework":"junit5"},"static_code_analysis":{"bool":true,"code_coverage_temp":["pmd","jacoco"]},"security_tools":{"bool":true,"security_tools_temp":["zap"]},"sonarcube":{"bool":true}}}';

const pattern = /"code_coverage_temp":\[("[A-z]+",?\s?)+\]/g;

let res = jsonStr.replace(pattern, match => {
    const parsedStr = JSON.parse(`{${match}}`);
      
    let obj = parsedStr.code_coverage_temp
                 .reduce((acc, curr) => (acc[curr] = true, acc), {});
  
    obj = JSON.stringify(obj);
  
    obj = obj.replace('{', '')
             .replace('}', '');
    
    return obj;
});

res = JSON.parse(res);
console.log(res);
```

It would be much simpler if you just parse the json and then operate on it.

```js
const jsonStr = '{"server":{"ip":"111.111.111.111","credentials":{"username":"fwesf","password":"fewfew"}},"pipeline":{"job":{"name":"gfhd"},"repository":{"name":"github","location":"fwqfw","credentials":{"username":"fsfs","password":"fdsfdsf"}},"build":{"language":"java","build_tool":"maven"},"test":{"bool":true,"test_type":"unit","testing_framework":"junit5"},"static_code_analysis":{"bool":true,"code_coverage_temp":["pmd","jacoco"]},"security_tools":{"bool":true,"security_tools_temp":["zap"]},"sonarcube":{"bool":true}}}';
const parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
const obj = parsedJson.pipeline.static_code_analysis;

obj.code_coverage_temp.forEach(str => obj[str] = true);

delete obj.code_coverage_temp;
console.log(parsedJson);
```

Comment: adding entire json:

Comment: nice answer i give upvote but not exactly what i need, copied entire json to my query

Comment: currently using online regex evaluator to try and get correct pattern

Comment: you want to match `"code_coverage_temp": ["pmd","jacoco"]` and replace it with `{"jacoco":true,"pmd":true}` right? So what will be the `key` of this new object?

Comment: current pattern ```"static_code_analysis":{"bool":true,"code_coverage_temp":["pmd","jacoco"]}```  and expected pattern i need to produce is ```"static_code_analysis":{"bool":true,"cobertura":true,"jacoco":false,"pmd":true }```

Comment: you can ignore the false value, just go with everything should be true

Comment: Thank you very much Yousaf, i dont know who down voted this but i upvote again

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (altough it's naive method):

```
const test = {
a: ['b', 'c'],
d: {
    e: ['d', 'f', 'g'],
    h: [],
    d: 'value'
  }
}

function parse(obj) {
  const vals = Object.values(obj)
  vals.forEach(v => {
    if (Array.isArray(v)) {
      v.forEach((o, i) => {
        if (typeof o == 'object') {
          parse(o)
        }
        if (typeof o == 'string') {
          {
            v[i] = {
              o: true
            }
          }
        }
        return o
      })
    } else if (typeof v == 'object') {
      parse(v)
    }
  })
}
```